# AutoIT CLose Save / Don't Save Prompt

Tags: python, automation, autoit

I want to close follwing Microsoft Office Save / Don't save prompt window using AutoIt(python version).

I tried based on the example given here : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import autoit
autoit.control_click("[Class:#NUIDialog]", "Button1")
```

Also tried

```
autoit.control_click("[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:1]", "Button1")
```

However, I'm getting fowling error :( :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "officetest.py", line 6, in <module>
    autoit.control_click("[CLASS:NetUIHWND; INSTANCE:1]", "Button1")
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyautoit-0.3-py2.7.egg\autoit\autoit.py", line 80, in wrapper
    raise AutoItError(err_msg)
autoit.autoit.AutoItError: send click message failed
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have set the class wrong on your first attempt (I can't fully try it because I have a different version of Word/Windows that assigns a different class to the window), as it looks like you included the # from the example. It would be better written as:

```
autoit.control_click("[Class:NUIDialog]", "Button1")
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps including the title gives better results.

```
autoit.control_click("[TITLE:Microsoft Word; CLASS:NUIDialog]", "Button1")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake ... You have to define the window you are working on by Title not Class so you can apply easily with clicking, exactly like this

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.control_click("[TITLE:Notepad]" , "Button1")
```

[Because control_send function just taking title, the text of window to access could be empty and the controlID means which button u want to click (left click by default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2m9x.png)